# how to use Openmap vector tiles with mapbox android Sdk

Tags: android, mapbox, openmaptiles

I am very new to Android development, but I managed to make bellow link work

https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/

Now I can load map by using mapbox API.

I just need one help , how can i use openmap vector tiles with this SDK, what do i need to change ?

I have installed vector tiles like this
http://mydomain:9090/styles/osm-bright/?vector#8/22.615/90.344

I did not find any documentation for this
Can any one please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use tiles hosted by a third-party, you need to set up a `TileSet` and then a `VectorSource` out of that set.

```
TileSet tileSet = new TileSet("2.1.0", TILE_SET_URL);
VectorSource source = new VectorSource(ID_SOURCE, tileSet);
```

Also important to note is, that when using vector tiles you need to define a source layer.

```
LineLayer lineLayer = new LineLayer(ID_LINE_LAYER, ID_SOURCE);
lineLayer.setSourceLayer("source-layer");
```

More on the source layer [here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-source-layer/), and a more elaborate example can be found in the Mapbox Demo App's [repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/labs/SymbolLayerMapillaryActivity.java#L1075-L1100).

Comment: Hi Lukasz, I am downloading the demo application to understand it better, 
regards to bellow line, in which files shall  I put this  under mapbox Android Sdk ?   ( I am quite new .. may be asking very silly question ) 
TileSet tileSet = new TileSet("2.1.0", TILE_SET_URL);
VectorSource source = new VectorSource(ID_SOURCE, tileSet);

Comment: Are you actually refer to this link https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/runtime-styling/  ?  to add my own tiles from openmaptiles ?

Comment: Hi Lukasz, I manged to install the android demo code and I found the places you mentioned above to change tiles. now only question i have, i followed this url https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/, now my qustion is to make mobox sdk into my applicaton, do i need download the full code of SDK from git hub or can i not just use tileset and Vector source in my application which i created by using the above url ? Please let me know

Comment: Paczos, so I have done bellow 

 TileSet tileSet = new TileSet("2.1.0", "http://192.168.1.7:9090/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf");
    VectorSource source = new VectorSource("2.1.0", tileSet);

now how do i replace mapbox api key with my tiles ?
 Mapbox.getInstance(this, "xxxxxx");

or am I doing totally wrong ?

please help me with this.

Comment: Paczos, I think i am getting it now  , here its saying how to add source and layer,
https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-dds-circle-layer/#add-a-source-and-a-circle-layer

Now i have 2 question , Please help me with ,

i am running openmaptiles which is running on  http://mydomain:9090/styles/osm-bright/?vector#8/22.615/90.344

in this case , what will be the right parameter for openmaptiles ? I dont see too much information about it in openmaptiles.

how can i set it as per Openmaptiles hosted in port 9090 ? 

I guess that will solve my problem, 
Thanks for the help

Comment: i did bellow but it crashed , please help me on this
public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                VectorSource vectorSource = new VectorSource(
                        "openmaptiles",
   "http://public:9090/styles/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" );
                mapboxMap.addSource(vectorSource);
                LineLayer lineLayer = new LineLayer("park_outline", "openmaptiles" );
                lineLayer.setSourceLayer("park");
                mapboxMap.addLayer(lineLayer);

Comment: Please follow https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/ if you have questions regarding initial map setup.